# Django how to extend generic View class

Tags: django, django-views

I noticed that I am setting site-wide context variables and request variables for many views on my site.  Naturally, this situation calls for inheritance.  If all of my view class-based views are inheriting from SiteView instead of the generic View, I can factor out all the commonalities into the SiteView child class. I can then inherit from SiteView on all my views.  But, I cannot get this to work.  Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class SiteView(View):
    ''' Extends the generic django-supplied View class '''

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(SiteView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Adds the variables required in the get request '''
        context = super(SiteView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

        context['common_var'] = 'some common value'
        context['user'] = request.user

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This throws the following TypeError:

```
    dispatch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:  Even though the correct answer is marked, there were other issues with the code. In particular, the get method of the SiteView should not have the following line:

```
context = super(SiteView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is because the View class does NOT have any get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the request to the `super().dispatch(..)` call:

```
class SiteView(View):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(SiteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

or you can just omit the `request` in the `dispatch` parameters, and thus pass it through `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
class SiteView(View):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(SiteView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is however probably more elegant, to pass the name of the function, like:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SiteView(View):

    # ...
```

**EDIT**: Note that a `View` has no `get(..)`, `post(..)`, etc. method. The `dispatch(..)` method will look if such method exists, and if so redirect to it. If such method does not exists, it will return a "405 Method Not Allowed" response.

Your `get(..)` function thus be implemented like:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SiteView(View):
    ''' Extends the generic django-supplied View class '''

    def render_to_response(self, context):
        # ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'common_var': 'some common value',
            'user': request.user
        }
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

It perhaps makes more sense to implement a "mixin" (perhaps with a subclass of the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin).

For example like:

```
class SiteViewMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(common_var='some common value', user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

and then use the mixin in another view, like:

```
class SomeView(SiteViewMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...
```

Comment: I get the message "'super' object has no attribute 'get' " when I added request

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct answer because it did address the error I had.  However, as my previous comment suggests, there were other parts of the code that needed a bit of tweaking as well.  In particular, after looking at Django's implementation of the View class, I found out that context = super(SiteView, self).get(*args, **kwargs) inside the get method caused an error as well since the View class does not have a get function, thus the error: "super's object has no attribute 'get' ".

Comment: @EarlyCoder: ah, that's indeed correct: a `View` has no `get(..)`, `post(..)`, etc.: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.base/View/ the `dispatch(..)` will look if such method is available and redirect accordingly. You thus should remove the `super(..).get(..)` call in your `get(..)` method.

Comment: @EarlyCoder: updated with the comment about `get(..)`. Perhaps it makes more sense to implement a mixin here?